# jQuery / Cycle / Background images

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I'm trying to get jQuery Cycle working on multiple background images, and am not sure why it doesn't work.  I just get no images showing up at all.

I have a fiddle here with sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6kjA6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#headerRotate').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 2000
    });
});

<div id="headerRotate">
    <div style="background:url('http://www.lilaclaneequestrian.com/_uploads/headers/692316_image-2.jpeg') no-repeat left top; height: 550px; background-size: 100%;"></div>
    <div style="background:url('http://www.lilaclaneequestrian.com/_uploads/headers/23874_image-4.jpeg') no-repeat left top; height: 550px; background-size: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure Are you including the plugin script? <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah it's there... as well as in the Fiddle example I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Setting some CSS on the divs took care of it: http://jsfiddle.net/6kjA6/5/

```
#headerRotate { width: 100%; }    
#headerRotate div { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: This does work, but I need the images to stretch to fit the width of the browser, hence the background-size: 100%;.  This fix removes that needed element.

Comment: If you're referring to the white border on the fiddle, that's due to browser default spacing on block elements. Use the following to remove: * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Comment: No, it's still not resizing as I need.  It needs to stretch to fit the entire width of the browser:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size2

Comment: The plugin that you're using sets inline widths on page load, so it will not respect window resizing. You might want to consider seeking a more responsive slider, as the one in place appears to be battling your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, ended up using this plugin instead.  http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/